# ¿Cómo aumentar rows cuando textarea se llene con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lo que busco es hacer un textarea parecido al de facebook(caja de comentarios), cuando este se llena o se presione "alt+enter", cree un row más en ves del scrollbar.

Comment: Hola Hans, puedes poner el codigo de tu formulario y lo que has intentado hasta ahora explicando por que no te funciona o qué fallos te da? ^^ Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen varias alternativas que te pueden servir para solventar ese problema de forma sencilla, tanto incrementar como decrementar el número de filas del textarea.

- [better-elastic-textarea](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-elastic-textarea)  ([ejemplo](http://chemerisuk.github.io/better-elastic-textarea/))
- [auto-resizing-textarea](https://stephanwagner.me/auto-resizing-textarea)

También puedes usar esta implementación manual:

[Solución original de SO ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    border: 0 none white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize () {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<textarea rows="1" style="height:1em;" id="text"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Jose, [te digo lo que a Sergio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56543/como-aumentar-rows-cuando-textarea-se-llene-con-jquery#comment101303_56549). Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Pues juraría que lo había puesto justo antes del snippet... lo busco y añado.

Comment: considero mejor la siguiente [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25621277/3045491) (parte 3 ) porque usa Jquery como pide OP y es mas simple a la vista

Comment: Gracias esto era justo lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es algo como esto:

```
$('#text-area').focus(function(){
        $(this).attr('rows', '4');
    });
```

(el ejemplo de código hace que aumente las rows cuando haces focus en el elemento).

pero claro, si quieres que aumente según el texto que ingresas tendrás que leer el evento de escritura y calcular dado lo ingresado si es necesario agrandar el text-area.

He encontrado esto, puede que te ayude:

```
function has_scrollbar(elem_id) 
{ 
    elem = document.getElementById(elem_id); 
    if (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) 
        alert("The element has a vertical scrollbar!"); 
    else 
        alert("The element doesn't have a vertical scrollbar."); 
}
```

Comment: Hola Sergio . Entiendo que con esta respuesta quieras ayudar y tambien ganar reputacion pero no es beneficioso contestar una pregunta tan pobre. El autor no se ha molestado en explicar con detenimiento su problema ni el codigo que tiene. Te recomiendo borrarla y cuando el autor se explique mejor, le das al boton de "recuperar" . Si esto le sirviera , no se va a esforzar en esta o siguientes preguntas porque "alguien me la responderá igualmente" . Un saludo ^^

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una solución sucia y tiene un molesto pestañeo al cambiar de altura, pero funciona.

Básicamente, cuando se ingresa texto se utiliza la propiedad scrollHeight
para recalcular la altura del recuadro.

Tuve que ponerlo en un timeout porque si no el listener se gatilla antes de tener el texto ya ingresado.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#mitextarea').on('change, keydown',function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {

      jQuery('#mitextarea')
       .css('height','auto') // <-- acá lo dejo scrollear por un instante
       .css('height',jQuery('#mitextarea')[0].scrollHeight+'px');

    },50);
  });
});
```

```css
#mitextarea {
    border: 1 #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea rows="1" style="height:1.1em;width:200px" id="mitextarea"></textarea>
```